# Why do I need a promise when Sequelize query is a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

If `Contracts.findAll` is a promise, why do I need to put a promise around that? or do I need a promise in this interaction between these 2 files? (Note: I do want separate files, but do I need `promise` and the `async/await`)?

**app.js**

```
(async () => {
    var results2 = await contracts.get();
    console.log(results2);
})();
```

**service.js**

```
exports.get = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Contract.findAll().then(contracts => {
            resolve(contracts[0].AccountNo_Lender)
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Wrapping a `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` around a Promise is an antipattern. And not handling the error case of that wrappped Promise makes it even worser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a wrapper Promise if `Contract.findAll()` already returns a promise.

The following code is equivalent:

```
exports.get = function () {
  return Contract.findAll().then(
    contracts => contracts[0].AccountNo_Lender
  );
};
```

Comment: But I do still need the `async/await` in `app.js`, correct?

Comment: @Rod if you want to use `await` then you have to use `async`. But you could also use `then` in your  `app.js` `contracts.get().then(results2 => console.log(results2)})`